# How do I get response from object sent via a request with wordpress api

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api

I have registered a api request the following way in the code, then in postman I call that request and add some params, but when I run the api request endpoint it returns null.
How do I return the data that's being sent?

```php
/**
 * This is our callback
 * function that embeds our phrase in a WP_REST_Response 
 */

function addProductFromCRM($data) {

  //$name = $data['name'];
  // rest_ensure_response() wraps the data we want to return into a WP_REST_Response, and ensures it will be properly returned.
  return rest_ensure_response($data);
}

/**
 * This function is where we register our routes for our example endpoint.
 */
function wp_register_crm_routes() {

  // register_rest_route() handles more arguments but we are going to stick to the basics for now.
  register_rest_route('crm/v1', '/addproduct/', array(
    // By using this constant we ensure that when the WP_REST_Server changes our readable endpoints will work as intended.
    'methods' => 'POST',
    // Here we register our callback. The callback is fired when this endpoint is matched by the WP_REST_Server class.
    'callback' => 'addProductFromCRM',
  ));
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'wp_register_crm_routes');
```

Answer (score 1):

What *addproduct* endpoint should return? JSON? You can do something like this:

```
function addProductFromCRM($request) {
    wp_send_json($request->get_params());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code snippet as per you need like on `isset($_POST)` or any other `callback function`. You must have the idea of your Register Route URL and must be working. you can use `wp_remote_get` or `wp_remote_post` as per your need. for more reference please check WordPress official site

```
$response = wp_remote_get("URL TO YOUR REGISTER ROUTE");
if ( is_array( $response ) ) {
  $response_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response );
  $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
  $body_data = json_decode($body);
}
```